# Create object from JSON with Parse & Java for Android

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

I have recently started doing Android development, I am using Parse.com and native Java for building the app. What I am trying to do is figure out how to create objects that are created from the JSON result via a callback from Parse [Parse.com](http://parse.com).

```
{
 "result": 
 {
 "count": 3,
 "lang": "en-US",
 "tasks": [
     {
      "ID": "0123",
      "Name": "Task 1",
      "AssingedTo": "Darxval",
      "Scope": "Home"
     },
     {
      "ID": "0124",
      "Name": "Task 2",
      "AssingedTo": "Darxval",
      "Scope": "Home"
     },
     {
      "ID": "0125",
      "Name": "Task 3",
      "AssingedTo": "Darxval",
      "Scope": "Home"
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

The method I call via Parse is shown below. 
(see documentation for more info on the method here):[Parse Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#cloudfunctions)

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("RetrieveTasks", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
  void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // do stuff with object
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried to change the Function callback to a class that takes in the json described as a bunch of strings and a ListArray of Task objects. But it does not create the object. It always want to use HashMap. Is there a way to turn the data into the object I want instead of a HashMap? Is there a interface I need to "implement" on my objects to allow the creation of the object on callback?

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What object is added to the HashMap? Is it a JSONObject?
If so, you can convert a JSONObject to whatever custom object you are looking for using a constructor, and the data from the JSONObject.

For example, if your JSONObject that is returned is called "output":

```
    try {
        JSONObject result = output.getJSONObject("result");
        int count = result.getInt("count");
        String lang = result.getString("lang");

        JSONArray tasks = result.getJSONArray("tasks");
        JSONObject firstObjectInArray = tasks.getJSONObject(0);
        String firstID = firstObjectInArray.getString("ID");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

etc.

Then use your constructor for your Object to create a new object:

```
    Object obj = new Object(count, lang, firstID);
```

etc.

[For more information](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: The hasMap(s) appears to just be Strings, and the ListArray<HashMap<String,String>> for the array.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit unclear on your original question, as I haven't ever worked with those Parse methods. But if what is returned is a string, could you use JSONObject newjsonobject = new JSONObject(string); to make the JSONObject, then use what I originally put in my answer to parse it?

Comment: I will try to explain a bit more clearly, maybe its also part of my ignorance on Java JSONObject, I will research more on that object, but the callback method from Parse takes the consturcted JSON from the API  I wrote in the Parse system, returning an HashMap of keyvalues, the keyvalues being strings and objects, the objects i have to cast to string or ListArray to retrieve the data. My hope was that I could say new FunctionCallback<ResultClass>() and have the class be created on the fly.